# how to sum float values catched with awk

Tags: awk

I want to sum the number of MB with awk::

```
$ docker images | awk  -t '{print $7}' | head

524MB
69.2MB
511MB
511MB
364MB
364MB
455MB
98.2MB
$
```

I cut left the 'M':

```
$ docker images | awk  -t '{print $7}'| grep MB | awk -F 'M' '{print $1}'
524
69.2
511
511
364
364
455
98.2
```

The bellow return a sum of zero

```
$ docker images | awk  -t '{print $7}'| grep MB | awk -F 'M' '{print $1}{s+=$$1}END{print s}'
```

Comment: Should this also convert `kB` and `GB` into `MB`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically this is enough:

Data:

```
$ cat file
524MB
69.2MB
511MB
511MB
364MB
364MB
455MB
98.2MB
```

Awk:

```
$ awk '{s+=$1}END{print s}' file
2896.4
```

So to translate your sample to awk only:

```
$ docker images | awk '/MB/{s+=$7}END{print s}'
```

Answer (score 2):

Considering that your all values will be in MB only.

```
docker images | awk '{sum+=$0+0} END{print sum}'
```

OR in case your command has some other size units too and you want to look for only MB size then try following.

```
docker images | awk '/[mM][bB]/{sum+=$0+0} END{print sum}'
```

***Explanation of `awk` code:***

```
awk '           ##Starting awk program from here.
{               ##Starting main BLOCK from here.
  sum+=$0+0     ##Creating a variable named sum whose value is keep adding to itself and $0+0 will take everything in line till all digits so it will remove the string MB part from this.
}               ##Closing main BLOCK for this program here.
END{            ##Starting END BLOCK for this awk program from here, which will be executed after Input_file reading is done.
  print sum     ##Printing variable sum here.
}'              ##Closing BLOCK here.
```